# How to pass a string value dynamically to a <div>(html)?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

In the html.erb file of rails app, I have a  html element. I want to pass the id to this div at run time. How can I achieve this? The below method does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = 'SkypeButton_Call_' + 'dsdsaf'+ '_1'
<div id=s></div>
 </script>`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a div in an `html.erb` file, then you can simply define that id like so:

`<div id='SkypeButton_Call_dsdsaf_1'></div>`

Please reply if this is not what you are looking for. Are you looking to work off of a ruby variable from your Rails controller?

If you have a ruby variable:

`@my_var = 'dsdsaf'`

Then you could do something like this:

`<div id="<%= @my_var %>"></div>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it didn't work for me. I have for loop: <% @users.each do |user| %> Inside which I am trying to create a string using the value from user and pass it to <div id="<%=user.name%>">. Could you please let me know the how to pass this string value to the div ID? Thanks

Comment: If I try your suggestion: `@my_var='dsdsaf' <div id="<%= @my_var %>"></div>`. The div id = '' when I inspect the page.

Comment: Do you mind showing your controller code and your html.erb code as well? It would be easier to get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You may put your div inside another div with an class identifier:

```
<div class='parent'> 
  <div></div> 
</div>
```

And then, by using jquery you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var s = 'SkypeButton_Call_' + 'dsdsaf'+ '_1';
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var child = $( ".parent" ).find("div"); //This var holds the child div of .parent
    child.attr("id", s); //This line sets id=s in the child div
  });
</script>
```

The result should be:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div id='SkypeButton_Call_dsdsaf_1'></div>
</div>
```